# Error: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8000' is therefore not allowed access

Tags: jquery, ajax, rotten-tomatoes

I am new to AJAX calls and I would like to mock up the rottentomatoes search page. I'm getting the correct JSON file but it won't load on my browser. I have been researching and have not found a solution. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var apikey = "qvq7jf4n29fv8m8pxqqyxsxg";
  var baseUrl = "http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0";
  var moviesSearchUrl = baseUrl + '/movies.json?apikey=' + apikey;

 $('form').submit(function (evt) {
    var $submitButton = $('#submit');
    var $searchField = $('#search');
    evt.preventDefault();
    $searchField.prop("disabled",true);
    $submitButton.attr("disabled", true).val("searching....");
    var query = $searchField.val();
    var rotten = moviesSearchUrl + '&q=' + encodeURI(query);

    $.ajax(rotten,

    function(data){

      if (data.items.length > 0) {
        $.each(data.items,function(i,movie) {
          movieHTML += '<li class="grid-25 tablet-grid-50">';
          movieHTML += '<a href="' + movie.title + '" class="image">';
          movieHTML += '<img src="' + movie.posters.original + '"></a></li>';
        }); // end each
      } else {
        movieHTML = "<p>No photos found that match: " + animal + ".</p>"
      }
      $('#movies').html(movieHTML);
      $searchField.prop("disabled", false);
      $submitButton.attr("disabled", false).val("Search");
    }); // end getJSON

  }); // end click

}); // end ready
```

Comment: You are running into the same-origin policy. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just needed to tweak .ajax to use jsonp.

Here is working jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/hvtz7kfv/2/

```
 $.ajax({
     dataType: "jsonp",
     url:  rotten,   
     success: searchCallback

});
```

Comment: I believe using jsonp, you can only get, not post... So for this scenario this should be work fine, but jsonp is not the answer to bypass same origin policy completely...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of sending an ajax request directly to rotten tomatoes, send a request to your server, have your server send the request to rotten tomatoes, and then relay that response back to your client. I don't think you should have to do that with a public API though.

Are you using Chrome? I think Chrome has some weird restrictions involving CORS and localhost.